# ExactTarget Data Extension integration with MySQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, data, sync

Is there a way to automatically export/update all Data Extensions in ExactTarget to MySQL tables?

Queries in ExactTarget is a bit limited when it comes to pulling data/reports quickly so it would be if something like this exists.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, not all of them at once.  The best way to get data in and out of SFMC is via flat file, so that would be my recommendation.

Data Extensions can be extracted using a [**Data Extract**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/) Activity and placed in your FTP share using a [**File Transfer**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/file_transfer_activity/) Activity.  These steps can all be automated in [**Automation Studio**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/).

You can also utilized the [**SFMC APIs**](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/) (SOAP and REST) to pull Data Extension data ([DataExtensionObject](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextensionobject/) = Data Extension row) and write it to your MySQL tables, but you'd have to build that outside of the SFMC Platform.